# Postgresql compare two rows recursively

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, recursion

I want to write a query where I can find track the downgraded versions for each id.

So here is the table;

```
id  version     ts 
1       3       2021-09-01 10:47:50+00
1       5       2021-09-05 10:47:50+00
1       1       2021-09-11 10:47:50+00
2       2       2021-09-11 10:47:50+00
2       6       2021-09-15 10:47:50+00
3       2       2021-09-01 10:47:50+00
3       4       2021-09-05 10:47:50+00
3       6       2021-09-15 10:47:50+00
3       1       2021-09-16 10:47:50+00
```

I want to print out something like that;

```
id:1 downgraded their version from 5 to 1 at 2021-09-11 10:47:50+00
id:3 downgraded their version from 6 to 1 at 2021-09-16 10:47:50+00
```

So when I run the query the output should be:

```
id  version  downgraded_to   ts 
1       5           1        2021-09-11 10:47:50+00             
3       6           1        2021-09-16 10:47:50+00
```

but I'm completely lost here.
Does it make sense to handle this situation in Postgresql? Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`lead`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-window.html) analytic function to get the next version and compare it with current version assuming that the version is of a numeric type.

> ```
> with next_vers as (
>   select t.*, lead(version) over(partition by id order by ts asc) as next_version
>   from(values
>    (1, 3, timestamp '2021-09-01 10:47:50'),
>    (1, 5, timestamp '2021-09-05 10:47:50'),
>    (1, 1, timestamp '2021-09-11 10:47:50'),
>    (2, 2, timestamp '2021-09-11 10:47:50'),
>    (2, 6, timestamp '2021-09-15 10:47:50'),
>    (3, 2, timestamp '2021-09-01 10:47:50'),
>    (3, 4, timestamp '2021-09-05 10:47:50'),
>    (3, 6, timestamp '2021-09-15 10:47:50'),
>    (3, 1, timestamp '2021-09-16 10:47:50')
>   ) as t(id, version, ts)
> )
> select *
> from next_vers
> where version > next_version
> ```
>
> ```
> id | version | ts                  | next_version
> -: | ------: | :------------------ | -----------:
>  1 |       5 | 2021-09-05 10:47:50 |            1
>  3 |       6 | 2021-09-15 10:47:50 |            1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6fdbf807a8a550ad8d5459c8c5ff40e7)*

Comment: I'm getting column reference "version" is ambiguous error.

Comment: ah so here is thing, version is string :/ version is not numeric type